# Gcc generates always mfence. Why?

Tags: c++11, gcc, memory-barriers

I am wondering why GCC 6.2 generates following assembly output:

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
    mfence
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 3
    mfence
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
    mfence
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

from source:

```
#include <atomic>

int main(){

 std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed); // why mfence instead of `nothing`?
 std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); // why mfence instead of sfence?
 std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); // why mfence instead of lfence?


  return 0;
}
```

Especially:

1. Why `mfence` instead of `nothing`?
2. Why `mfence` instead of `sfence`?
3. Why `mfence` instead of `lfence`?

Comment: @kennytm: That's not particularly surprising given OP's code does not actually do anything that would require fencing.

Comment: That's only at -O0. At -O1, on x86, only seq_cst actually generates a fence, all others are ignored.